# In Spring boot, I'm trying to create another .property file that functions like messages.property, Is that possible?

Tags: spring-boot, internationalization, thymeleaf, properties-file

So I'm trying to create another .property file (called labels.properties) that i can use in Thymeleaf like this:

```
<div th:text=#{property.from.labels}></div>
```

Right now I just add labels.properties in the root of resource folder, for now its not working. The purpose of this is I want to separate the property file that handles the error messages from texts for labels & buttons.

1. Is that possible?
2. if yes, how to do it?
3. if yes again, can I do internationalization like adding labels_ja.properties (Japanese)?

Comment: I think you need i18n for this purpose, check this:  https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-internationalization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the naming (and location) of the message bundles by configuring the `spring.messages.basename` property. For example:

```
spring.messages.basename=labels
```

By doing so, Spring will look for messages within `classpath:labels.properties` and `classpath:labels_{locale}.properties`, such as `classpath:labels_ja.properties`.

If you want to use this in addition to the regular `messages.properties` file, you can use a comma separated value:

```
spring.messages.basename=messages,labels
```

The first one within that comma separated list will take priority over the other ones. If you have a `property.from.labels` in both `messages.properties` and `labels.properties`, the one within `messages.properties` would be chosen in this example.

This can also be found within the Spring Boot Reference Documentation at the [Internationalization](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-internationalization.html) section.

Comment: what if i put labels.properties in a folder like resources/new_folder/labels.properties? do I need to add new_folder/labels in spring.messages.basename?